# IS $f(z) = x^3 + i(1-y)^3$ analytic and where is it differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where is $f(z) = x^3 + i(1-y)^3$ analytic and where is it differentiable?

I have taken Cauchy-Riemann equations as follows:

$$u(x,y) = x^3$$
$$v(x,y) =(1-y)^3$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=3x^2$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-3(1-y)^2$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \implies 0=0$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\implies -3(1-y)^2=3x^2\iff (1-y)^2 =x^2$$

Surely this isn't open on any neighborhood?

---

How do I determine differentiability?

Answer (score 1):

The function is differentiable where the CREs hold (and the derivatives are continuous), that is,
$$x^2=-(y-1)^2\ .$$
Since a (real) square cannot be negative, this is the single point $x=0$, $y=1$.  As you state, the region of differentiability does not contain an open neighbourhood of any of its points: so the function is analytic nowhere.

Comment: So it is differentiable with CRE and continuous partial derivatives, but for differentiation it does not require CREs on an open neighborhood. So analytic at a point is strictly stronger of a condition than differentiable

Comment: Correct.  Note that you made a slip in your algebra - I just picked it up and have changed my answer.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. Apologies

Comment: It is definitely partial derivatives at the point, here they are all $0$. Does that say that it is continuous at the point?

Comment: It's partial derivatives "as functions": they are polynomials and hence continuous everywhere.

Comment: But at the point they are equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Not sure I understand what you are asking.